cqlsh taking too long to respond for connectivity
In our application we have a monitoring service for cassandra which periodically executes a set of nodetool commands to check and update the db status. It also executes cqlsh <ip-address> <port> -e quit to check db connectivity. Recently, we have seen an issue where this command takes inconsistent time to respond.
$ date; time sudo docker container exec -it cassandra cqlsh <ip-address> <port> --request-timeout=6000 --connect-timeout 3600 -e quit

Fri Mar 8 23:16:40 UTC 2024
top
real 1m31.640s
user 0m0.105s
sys 0m0.043s

Other results show normal completion time.
$ date; time sudo docker container exec -it cassandra cqlsh <ip-address> <port> --request-timeout=6000 --connect-timeout 3600 -e quit
Fri Mar 8 23:15:36 UTC 2024
 
real 0m1.883s
user 0m0.092s
sys 0m0.080s 

I am not really sure how to debug this or what could be causing this; we are suspecting something at the system level like threads getting stopped [the reason behind this is in the logs we have lines like 2024-03-08T19:47:27.256+0000: 18518472.791: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 6.9855204 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0005202 seconds and the time stamps almost are inline with the timestamps on which the call is responding slow but not sure how to tackle this.
Any suggestions...

This is just a symptom. The most likely issue is that the nodes are busy or overloaded so they are taking a long time to respond.
You will need to review the Cassandra logs to determine the root cause. Things to look for are long GC pauses (or lots of short GCs which add up to a long pause), JVM pauses, high CPU or disk IO utilisation, and dropped mutations.
As a side note, your cqlsh check is not optimal because it needs to run the cqlsh utility just to verify whether the Cassandra process is listening for CQL connections. This ends up using more resources than is necessary and can impact the performance of the container.
A better way to implement it is to use Docker's native healthcheck. For example, to check if Cassandra is listening for clients on CQL port 9042:
services:
  cassandra:
    ...
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "netstat -an | grep -q 9042"]
      ...

This method lets Docker quickly verify whether the container is "healthy". For details, see the Docker healthcheck docs. Cheers!
